# I want to use the add dynamic function for a begin overlap UE4, and i already have a box collision on my player pawn. How do I reference the Box?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

But i dont know how to reference the existing box in this line:

```
void ARasenmaeher::BeginPlay()
{
    ????????()->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &ARasenmaeher::OnBeginOverlap);
}
```

what do I write instead of "????"

Comment: You can reference `Box` using its name, which was declared and defined somewhere. However `???()` is a function, or a method, does it return a Box object ? Anyway, please add your box definition in your post or your question will be closed for lack of debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

for example if you are using a box component like this : `UBoxComponent* TriggerBox;` you will write `TiggerBox->OnComponentBeginOverlap ...`